# Whenever the "description" in PostWidget" comes in from the backend and is super long the Widget get super wide. How do I prevent this?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Whenever the "description" in PostWidget" comes in from the backend and is super long the Widget gets super wide and causes the app UI to go out of proportion[image]. How do I prevent this?

PostWidget CSS:

```
return (
 <div className="flex p-5 mb-5 rounded-lg border bg-zinc-200 drop-shadow-lg border-b shadow-2xl" style={{marginBottom: '40px', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
 <div className="flex flex-col justify-between mr-2" style={{marginRight: '2rem'}}>
 <Friend
 friendId={postUserId}
 name={name}
 subtitle={location}
 userPicturePath={userPicturePath}
 />
 <p>
 {description}
 </p>


</div>
 <div className="w-58">
 {picturePath && (
 <img
 src={`http://localhost:3001/assets/${picturePath}`}
 alt="post"
 className="w-64"
 />
        )}
 </div>
 </div>
  );
};

export default PostWidget;
```

Below is the Widget that contains PostWidget. Well, It actually contains PostsWidget but PostsWidget is just a Widget that fetches data from the backend and Maps it to PostWidget. There is no CSS in PostsWidget.

```
return (
 
 <Box>
 <Navbar className="relative w-full"
 
 />

 <Box
 width="100%"
 padding="2rem 6%"
 display={isNonMobileScreens ? "flex" : "block"}
 gap="0.5rem"
 justifyContent="space-between"
 >
 <Box flexBasis={isNonMobileScreens ? "26%" : undefined}>
 <RandomHobbyWidget/>
 </Box>
 <Box
 flexBasis={isNonMobileScreens ? "42%" : undefined}
 mt={isNonMobileScreens ? undefined : "2rem"}
 
 
 >
 <MyPostWidget picturePath={picturePath} />
 <PostsWidget userId={_id} />
 
 </Box>

 <Box
 flexBasis={isNonMobileScreens ? "26%" : undefined}
 >
 <WeatherWidget/>

 
 </Box>
 
 </Box>

 
 </Box>

    );
};
```

Comment: css, word-break: break-word; can help you :)